# Programmatically select a tabbaritem in "More"

Tags: iphone, uitabbar

I am using UITabbarController with 8 to 9 items (these are UINavigation controllers)

It is easy to select an item programmatically using

`tabbarcontroller.selectedIdex = x;`

if x value is between 0 to 4 then it's work as expected but if it's greater than 4 then it's select "More" as a view controller.

How can we programmatically select an item under "More" list ?

any help would be appreciated..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This only works in OS 3.0, but in order to access the items higher than the 'More' index you need to use  the `selectedViewController` property and pass the pointer to a specific `UIViewController` instead of using `selectedIndex`.

Comment: `self.tabBarController.selectedViewController = [self.tabBarController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:5];`
I did that way but no luck, could you please provide me some snippet for that.

Comment: Did you verify that the viewControllers array has the proper values in it? Modifying the array can end up truncating things. You may have to maintain your own separate viewController array.

Comment: It is selecting but highlighting, now what to do ?